# URI 1101 Sequence of Numbers and Sum

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int M,N,i=0,sum=0;

    while(M>0 || N>0){

        scanf("%d%d",&M,&N);

        if(M<=0 || N<=0){
            break;
        }

        else if(M==N){ printf("%d Sum=%d\n",N,M); }

        else if(M<N){
            for(i=M; i<=N; i++){
                printf("%d ",i);
                sum+=i;
            }
            printf("Sum=%d\n",sum);
            sum=0;
        }

        else if(M>N){
            for(i=N; i<=M; i++){
                printf("%d ",i);
                sum+=i;
            }
            printf("Sum=%d\n",sum);
            sum=0;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

what is wrong with this code? URI judge saying 100% wrong answer but I tried all the test cases and it passed in those cases

Comment: Please explain what it should do at least. We can’t say what’s wrong without knowing that

Comment: If judge says that it is 100% wrong and you say that it passes all test cases, then you have a misunderstanding. Maybe show the test cases you tried here, but it seems that they are different from judges.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Once the shown code compiles and runs (which it probably will once you fixed the formatting https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help ) show input along with expected output and actual output.

Comment: I got a feeling that you should reninitialise some or all of your variable inside the outer loop. If you do not, then you might pass any single test case but not any second  or further test cases in one run.

Comment: Edit your question. Fix formatting. Explain what this code is supposed to do, what is the input and what is the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but before while loop you should get `scanf("%d%d",&M,&N);` one time.

Because the `m` and `n` is not defined.

Like this way :

```
scanf("%d%d",&M,&N); 

while(M>0 || N>0){

    scanf("%d%d",&M,&N);

    if(M<=0 || N<=0){
        break;
    }

    ...
```